# Integrating Heaviside Step Function of two Variables

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, step-function

Suppose we have a definite integral like $$ I=\int_0^\infty dx \int_0^\infty dy \,  Θ(α-x-y) $$
where $a \in R_+^*$ and $Θ$ is the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function). Of course this is easy in that we can find the answer without working with integrals,  since it's simply the area of a triangle with vertices $O(0,0)$ , $A(a,0)$, $B(0,a)$, which is $\frac{a^2}{2}$.

However trying to work the integral out doesn't seem so trivial (to me at least). One could, naively, do for example $I=\int_0^\infty dx \int_0^{a-x} dy = -\infty$ (since $Θ=0$ for $y \ge a-x$) which is obviously wrong- somehow $Θ$ should affect both integral limits, but I can't see how this can happen. Probably I'm misunderstanding the definition of $Θ(α-x-y)$.

**EDIT** : As @John Polcari pointed out, in the above exaple, we should limit $x$ such that $a-x \ge 0$, so we should have $I= \int_0^\infty dx \int_0^{a-x}Θ(a-x) \, dy $ which indeed gives the right result. However this seems to me like adding the $Θ(α-x)$ by hand, which is no different from the first argument with the triangle's area. Is there a prettier-more strict- way of doing it?

Comment: In your example integral (the one that doesn't work), there needs to be a second limit on a-x in the y integral to deal with the possibility a-x<0 (probably some type of min or max operation).  Something similar is probably needed on  the x integral.  Then things should work out.

Comment: More precisely, the y integral is fine, but the way to keep a-x from going negative is to set the upper limit of the x integral to a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formally correct result is $$\int\limits_0^\infty  {dz\,\Theta \left( {a - z} \right)}  = a\,\Theta \left( a \right)$$

In case it is unclear to see how to apply this:

By implication from above
$$\int\limits_0^\infty  {dz\,z} \,\Theta \left( {a - z} \right) = \frac{{{a^2}}}{2}\Theta \left( a \right)$$
Then
$$\begin{array}{l}
\int\limits_0^\infty  {dx\int\limits_0^\infty  {dy\,\Theta \left( {a - x - y} \right)} }  = \int\limits_0^\infty  {dx\left( {a - x} \right)\Theta \left( {a - x} \right)} \\
 = a\int\limits_0^\infty  {dx\,\Theta \left( {a - x} \right)}  - \int\limits_0^\infty  {dx\,x\;\Theta \left( {a - x} \right)} \\
 = {a^2}\Theta \left( a \right) - \frac{{{a^2}}}{2}\Theta \left( a \right) = \frac{{{a^2}}}{2}\Theta \left( a \right)
\end{array}$$
The final step function is appropriate because the if $a<0$, the answer really is zero.
$\hspace{0pt}$

Answer (score 2):

Let $I$ be the integral defined by

$$I=\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \Theta(a-x-y)\,dy\,dx\tag1$$

Enforcing the substitution $u=a-x-y$ in $(1)$ reveals

$$I=\int_0^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{a-x} \Theta(u)\,du\,dx\tag2$$

Changing the order of integration in $(2)$ we find that

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_{-\infty}^a \int_0^{a-u} \Theta(u)\,dx\,du\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^a \Theta(u) \int_0^{a-u} (1)\,dx\,du\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^a \Theta(u) (a-u)\,du\\\\
&=\int_0^a (a-u)\,du\\\\
&=\frac12a^2
\end{align}$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: Can you give some more detail on how you reached the third step where you changed the order of integration? Also if you don't do that and instead calculate the integrals in (2) you get the wrong result, what's the catch? Thanks

Comment: To better understand the interchange of integration, draw a picture of the region of integration.  Your statement that the integrals are not equal upon interchanging the order is untrue.  They are equal.